# Laravel: "sending" a model with relationship to Vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm starting to learn how to use Vue and Laravel. So I'm writting some Vue components to replace some parts of the blades.

In my application I have a `Sugerencia` (suggest) model. Of course I have `users` models and many others, but I need those two for this question

My `SugerenciaController@index` is quite simple:

```
public function index()
{
  $sugerencias = Sugerencia::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
  ->with('user')
  ->paginate(10);
  return view('sugerencias.index', compact('sugerencias'));
}
```

In my `sugerencias/index.blade.php` I "send" the `$sugerencia` to Vue with:

```
@foreach ($sugerencias as $sugerencia)
   ...
   <user-info :sugerencia="{{ $sugerencia }}"></user-info>
   ...
@endforeach
```

And works as intended. `user-info` is a Vue component that formats and displays the user's info. In Vue, to access the user's name, I use `{{ sugerencia.user.name }}` in my template. So far, so good. But this works only in the collection.

Then I have my `SugerenciaController@show` method, which is as simple as

```
public function show(Sugerencia $sugerencia) {
  return view('sugerencias.show', compact('sugerencia'));
}
```

I assumed that in my `sugerencias\show.blade.php` I could use the same call for the `user-info` Vue component as:

```
...
<user-info :sugerencia="{{ $sugerencia}}"></user-info>
...
```

...but I can't, since it's not "sending" the `user` relationship. I assume its because I'm not using the `->with('user')` as I did in the collection.

In the `mounted()` method I placed a `console.log(this.sugerencia)` and I get all sugerencia's data, but not the user data (just the `user_id` foreign key)

So question is, how do I "append" the `user` relationship to the `sugerencia` model, kinda like eager loading. I want to do something that as trivial as `$sugerencia->user->name` in the ORM

Please forgive me if my English isn't clear enough and feel free to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I would decouple the logic here and load the page and vue component with a null value and then do ajax requests to get the required data. Or implement a standardized way of getting data from the controller to the vue components without having specific variables in my `view` blade templates.

However, for your particular question, you could use [Lazy eagar loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) like this:

```
public function show(Sugerencia $sugerencia) {
  $sugerencia->load('user');
  return view('sugerencias.show', compact('sugerencia'));
}
```

From the docs:

> Sometimes you may need to eager load a relationship after the parent model has already been retrieved. For example, this may be useful if you need to dynamically decide whether to load related models:

Comment: Great! Yeah it solves my problem. As I said I'm starting with Vue. So the best way to do what I want is an `axios` call on loading the component to get user's data? why?

Comment: I mean, in the index, wouldn't be like the n+1 query problem? Isn't more effective to do a single query? Just wanting to learn

Comment: In my opinion, yes getting the ALL the data via ajax, because then you can start to build your vue application with separate components that are all independant from one another like "modules". You dont have to use ajax for everything though, you can still pass data in on page load but I wouldnt want to do it directly like `<user-info :sugerencia="{{ $sugerencia}}"></user-info>`.  If you want to post a new question with the same code and ask something like "How can I pass data to from my laravel backend to my vue application without using blade logic" I would be happy to show you an example

Comment: I tried but it says it's duplicated... let me try and post again with lesser code. I really appreciate your time and knowledge, and willingness to share